# Как выводить методы оплаты при нулевой цене товара Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую интернет магазин скорее как каталог, так как я оптовый производитель. Хочу чтобы цены пока были 0.Но методы оплаты не отображаются если цена меньше единицы. Можно ли как то отобразить методы оплаты при любой цене даже 0?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать товары с нулевой ценой доступными для заказа. Тогда для них заработает вся товарная логика Woocommerce.

Код для добавления в functions.php

```
// делаем товары с нулевой ценой доступными для заказа
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'is_product_purchasable', 20, 2 );
function is_product_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( '' === $product->get_price() || $product->get_price() == 0 ) $purchasable = true; 
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Для обычных товаров должно сработать.